# remove one child and select another one

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, parent-child

I have this html code:

```
<div id="step-1st">
  <pre style="display:none"></pre>
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

I like to remove `textarea` and show the `pre` with the below code:

```
$("#step-1st textarea").remove().parent().children("pre").show();
```

Surely this can be done easily with more than on line, but i want to know how to do so with one line.

Comment: I've got just one question: why on Earth??

Comment: You're deleting the item before you get the parent of it. Why does this need to be on one line? Surely you can get the parent before you remove the child element and then show the correct element after in 2 or 3 lines?

Comment: @kirelagin I just want to see if it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#step-1st textarea").prev("pre").show().end().remove();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/q3cMn/

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.

```
$("#step-1st pre").next().remove().end().show();
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/793GV/)

There are many ways to do it, but you are most likely going to need to use [`.end()`](http://api.jquery.com/end/) to get back to the original selector.

Answer (score 1):

if you have more than one `<pre>` elements:

```
$("#step-1st textarea").parent().children("pre").show().end().end().remove();
```